# How do I fix my locale settings on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my linode?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, localization

My Dropbox installation on my linode is failing with the error:

```
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

When I run :

```
locale
```

I get the output:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

So it seems that the LC_CTYPE and LC_ALL settings are incorrect. How do I fix them ?
I have tried:

```
sudo update-locale LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

output:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

EDIT: I have also tried this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

output:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_AU.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_BW.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_CA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_DK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_GB.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_HK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_IE.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_IN.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_NG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_NZ.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_PH.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_SG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZM.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZW.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

Doing the following seems to make it work. But I how can I make it permanent?
I did:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 (VPS @ Linode):

Edit /etc/environment and add the following line:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Note: pay attention to the exact error. Ensure the language (in question) has been generated correctly and set: /etc/default/locale accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked for me.

I added to the end of `/etc/default/locale` the following line:

```
LC_ALL="es_CL.UTF-8"
```

To replicate the error try using perl: type `perl` in the command line and your error should appear (to quit perl press `CTRL+C`). Then change the file, logout (`exit` command) and then login again; now try typing `perl` and the error should be gone.